# plt.show() wont display my plot (Google Colab). Please assist

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, google-colaboratory

I don't understand why the plot wont display. I have tried everything in my knowledge to fix this problem and still don't understand, I am only new to programming. Please advise on how this can be fixed. I assume that Google Colab has the necessary packages installed to run the code successfully.

The code I tried is shown below;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

k      = 1.0 # Spring constant
m      = 1.0 # Mass
cycles = 2.0 # No. of periods to integrate over
x0     = 1.0 # Initial displacement
v0     = 0.0 # Initial velocity

def leapfrog( steps ):
"""Solve the simple harmonic motion equations for several oscillation cycles,
assuming that the mass (m) and spring constant (k) are defined in the
global space.
"""

omega = (k/m)**0.5
delta = 2.0*cycles*np.pi/omega/steps
x     = np.empty( steps+1 )
v     = np.empty( steps+1 )
t     = np.empty( steps+1 )
t\[0\]  = 0.0
x\[0\]  = x0
v\[0\]  = v0 + 0.5*delta*x\[0\]\*omega**2.0
for i in range(steps):
t\[i+1\] = t\[i\] + delta
v\[i+1\] = v\[i\] - omega\*\*2*delta*x\[i\]
x\[i+1\] = x\[i\] + delta\*v\[i+1\]
return t, x, v

def l2_error_norm( t , x ):
"""Calculate the L2 relative error norm."""
steps  = len( x ) - 1
omega  = (k/m)\*\*0.5
l2_err = 0.0
l2     = 0.0
for i in range(steps):
x_exact = x0*np.cos( omega*t\[i\] )
l2_err += (x\[i\] - x_exact)\*\*2.0
l2     += x\[i\]\*\*2.0
return (l2_err/l2)\*\*0.5

# This loop integrates the SHM equations repeatedly using an increasing

# number of steps (doubling at each loop iteration).

n        = 14
steps    = 8
l2_error = np.empty( n )
delta    = np.empty( n )
for i in range(0,n):
t, x, v     = leapfrog( steps )
delta\[i\]    = (k/m)\**0.5*(t\[1\]-t\[0\])
l2_error\[i\] = l2_error_norm( t , x )
plt.plot( t , x )
plt.show( block=False )
steps \*= 2

plt.figure()
plt.loglog( delta , l2_error , 'o' )
plt.loglog( delta , l2_error\[0\]*(delta/delta\[0\])\*\*1.0 )
plt.loglog( delta , l2_error\[0\]*(delta/delta\[0\])\*\*2.0 )
plt.loglog( delta , l2_error\[0\]\*(delta/delta\[0\])\*\*3.0 )
plt.show()\`\`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, all `\` should be removed. It is not needed here and I do not know what purpose they are serving in this context. Having them in there should have given you loads of `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`. They are only used in python as a means of continuing code on the next line if it is too long. For example:

```
n = [1,2,3, \
    4,5]
```

Please take care to format and style python properly and all will be well in the future :)

Once removing those pesky `\` and adding missing indentation everything works! Here is the fixed code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

k = 1.0 # Spring constant
m = 1.0 # Mass
cycles = 2.0 # No. of periods to integrate over
x0 = 1.0 # Initial displacement
v0 = 0.0 # Initial velocity

def leapfrog(steps):
  """Solve the simple harmonic motion equations for several oscillation cycles,
  assuming that the mass (m) and spring constant (k) are defined in the
  global space.
  """
  omega = (k/m)**0.5
  delta = 2.0*cycles*np.pi/omega/steps
  x = np.empty(steps + 1)
  v = np.empty(steps + 1)
  t = np.empty(steps + 1)
  t[0] = 0.0
  x[0] = x0
  v[0] = v0 + 0.5*delta*x[0]*omega**2.0

  for i in range(steps):
    t[i+1] = t[i] + delta
    v[i+1] = v[i] - omega**2*delta*x[i]
    x[i+1] = x[i] + delta*v[i+1]

  return t, x, v

def l2_error_norm(t, x):
  """Calculate the L2 relative error norm."""
  steps = len(x) - 1
  omega = (k/m)**0.5
  l2_err = 0.0
  l2 = 0.0
  for i in range(steps):
    x_exact = x0*np.cos(omega*t[i])
    l2_err += (x[i] - x_exact)**2.0
    l2 += x[i]**2.0
  return (l2_err/l2)**0.5

# This loop integrates the SHM equations repeatedly using an increasing

# number of steps (doubling at each loop iteration).

n = 14
steps = 8
l2_error = np.empty(n)
delta = np.empty(n)
for i in range(0,n):
  t, x, v = leapfrog(steps)
  delta[i] = (k/m)**0.5*(t[1] - t[0])
  l2_error[i] = l2_error_norm(t, x)
  plt.plot(t, x)
  plt.show(block=False)
  steps *= 2

plt.figure()
plt.loglog(delta, l2_error , 'o' )
plt.loglog(delta, l2_error[0] * (delta/delta[0])**1.0)
plt.loglog(delta, l2_error[0] * (delta/delta[0])**2.0)
plt.loglog(delta, l2_error[0] * (delta/delta[0])**3.0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Ayliah, thank you for your response. I appreciate your help. I have tried your code and it still has not fixed my problem. I am using Google Colab do you think there is more underlying problem? Thanks again.

Comment: I just ran it on colab and had no problems! Try this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/142WS-T1zYnSFIQsj8wO0iAoXL4nj6zlZ?usp=sharing).

Could you share what error message you are getting?

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much Ayliah.